# Why RPI need such a high current?

Tags: power-supply

I am little bit confused. All my colleagues tell me that I need 2.5 or 3A power source. Indeed, it does not work with with "smaller" source.

However, the general knowledge and this site (and many others) https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-power tell that the consumption is much lower.

Why and when it needs such a high current from source?

Comment: The 2.5 amp will be suggested for the Pi3 model, not the Pi Zero models.

Answer (score 0):

As @joan said in a comment the 2.5 Amp power source is recommended for Pi3 B model (the most common one) for Raspberry Pi Zero and Raspberry Pi Zero W models the recommended power is much lower (1.2 Amp) if you want to know what is the power source you need for your model I recommend to consult this table: https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#topPower

Comment: Thanks and sorry for irrelevant link, but question still stands. If (for example 3B) cannot draw more than 2A, why it crashes with source over 2A (below 2.5A)?

Comment: @matousc That bears no relation to your actual question.  If you have asked the wrong question please **clarify what you are asking by editing your question**.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi3 will run quite happily on a **quality** 1A supply.

If it does not work you have a PS or cable problem.

See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Many Pi users do not understand "current" - provided the voltage is correct it will run - of course this means the PS has to be able to deliver the correct voltage at the current actually required.